# A method to add a digit to an existing number at certain index

Tags: java

I have a  question in my homework that wants me to create a method that will have 3 parameters:

1. int number (random number)
2. int digit (a digit to add to the number)
3. int index (adding the number at this specified index, so the last number will be 0, the next 1 etc)

Now we just started to learn Java and we are not allowed to use any of the magic methods they supply , only the basic operations..and all the loops and conditions of course..

I did create a method to count the numbers but my problem is adding the digit to the number.

```
public void insertDigit (int number, int digit, int index) {

    int newNumber;
    int numberOfDigits = 0;
    int temp = 0;

    while (number != 0) {

        temp = number % 10;
        number /= 10;
        numberOfDigits++;
    }


}
```

For example: someObject.insertDigit(345, 5, 1) - this is the input

output - 3145

Comment: Can you post the method which you created?

Comment: Please show your code so far.

Comment: Also please explain what a "magic method" is and why can't you use it?

Comment: Please also provide example input and output so we can clearly answer the question and you can show that you understand the question. Understanding the question is key to programming.

Comment: Ok I did post what I did so far but i mentioned I didn't do anything except getting the number of digits, and by magic i mean something like math.pow...something that is coming from a special library. I don't know why I'm getting - from people about this q @skiwi

Comment: You are getting a lot of -1's, because you have: 1) Used foul wording, 2) Not included your own code, 3) Have not provided example input/output. People really dislike that here.

Comment: Your solution incorrectly computes the length of number zero: it has one digit, but your loop says it's zero digits.

Comment: i added example @skiwi

Comment: Are you sure that your example is correct? I don't think so - from your description it looks like you want `3455`, with `5` inserted between indexes `1` and `0`. If I'm wrong, tell me what should be the result of `insertDigit(345, 9, 1)`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I have the same feeling aswell. I tried to answer this question, but then I got confused as to where to actually insert the digit. Because there is no such thing as `at index 0`. It always has to be between some other indices.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight the example is quite clear, he wants to add the 5 to the second digit (index 1): so with 345 you add the 5 on the second digit and you get 395. I'm just not sure what should happen if the sum is more than 9...

Comment: @EdgarBoda That's the thing - I think OP misunderstands the problem, precisely because there's no logically sound approach to solving the "what happens if the resultant digit is above `9`" problem.

Comment: @skiwi you are right, i asked a class mate and i changed the example

Comment: @dasblinkenlight you are right, i changed the example, sorry

Comment: @user804968 The example is still incorrect, because `1` is inserted at index 2, not 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a learning exercise, I will briefly explain the math behind the problem; you will have to write all your code to satisfy the assignment.

In order to complete your assignment, you would need to do two things:

1. **Chop off the last `k` digits from a number** - given a number `N` of `m` digits and a small number `k`, produce two numbers, `A` and `B`, such that `A` has `m-k` digits from the front of the number `N`, and `B` has the last `k` digits
2. **Combine two numbers into one by appending the second number to the first one** - Given two numbers `A` and `B`, make a third number `N` by appending the digits of `B` behind the digits of `A`.

Given solutions to (1) and (2), you should be able to solve your problem by first chopping off the number `N` into `A` and `B` at the position `index`, appending the required digit `D` to the number `A`, producing `AD`, and finally appending `B` to `AD` for the final result of `ADB`.

Here is how you solve #1: construct a power of ten equal to the index `k` at which you want to cut your number, and compute

```
int pow10k = (int)Math.pow(10, k); // If using Math is not allowed, compute pow(10,k) with a simple loop
int A = N / pow10k;
int B = N % pow10k;
```

Here is how you solve #2: count the number of digits `k` in the number being appended (your post shows an almost working way of doing it), then compute the corresponding power of ten. Do the result computation as follows:

```
// Append B to A
int k = numDigits(B);
int pow10k = (int)Math.pow(10, k);
int AB = A*pow10k + B;
```

Comment: Yours is better worded. I'll just delete mine.

Comment: You can avoid the while loop (in the spirit of using Math anyhow) and find the number of digits in k with (int)(Math.log10(k)+1); with 0 being the exception obviously.

Comment: @leigero Yes, that's the mathematical way of doing it. I wanted the OP to reuse some of his code, though.